# 2000 PDF generate to be generated from JRXML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

My web application triggers a batch file.
The batch file will trigger a simple java and it hit the DB and brings 2000 records with an ID.

There will be 2000 xml file that matches the name of the ID and it read one file and passes it to [JRXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports#JRXML). From JRXML it generates it as PDF. Store the PDF in the specified path. 
To generate 1 PDF file it took 30sec. but when I run in the loop for the 2000 records.  It is taking 14hrs to complete.

Any best design to achieve this? Or your input is  useful

```
document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("D:/StoxxComponents/XMLMergeOut/DK5NY_11.xml")); // file name will be dynamically changing. 

JRXmlDataSource jrds = new JRXmlDataSource(document, "/factsheet");

InputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:/StoxxComponents/Jrxml" + "/"
                + "Template1-MainReport.jrxml"); // this is static 
// load the input file
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

// Compiling Report Designs
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(jasperDesign);

// Creating JasperPrint Object
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                jasperReport, null, jrds);

// Exporting the report
OutputStream PDF_OUTPUT = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/StoxxComponents/GeneratedPDF/test"+index+".pdf"));

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, PDF_OUTPUT);
```

this will be executed in for loop for 2000 times. so it is taking 14hrs. to generate 1 PDF it took 30secs.

Please advice how to tune this code and logic.